Find all subspaces of $\mathbb{F}^{n\times n}$ containing matrices $B_1,B_2$, such that $AB_i=B_iA \Rightarrow A=\lambda I_n$.
Here is a homework question: Find all subspaces of $\mathbb{F}^{n\times n}$ containing square matrices $B_1,B_2$, such that for any $A\in \mathbb{F}^{n\times n}$, $$AB_i=B_iA \quad (i=1,2)\Rightarrow A=\lambda I_n$$
My thoughts: Here is a non-trivial example. Let
$$ B_1=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & \cdots &\cdots & 0\\
0 & 0 & \ddots &\cdots &0\\
\vdots & \vdots  & \ddots &\ddots &\vdots \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\\end{pmatrix}
,\quad  B_2=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & \cdots &\cdots & 0\\
1 & 0 & \cdots &\cdots &0\\
\vdots & \ddots  & \ddots &\vdots &\vdots \\
0 & 0 & \ddots & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 & 0\\\end{pmatrix}
$$
It can shown that
$$ \{A\in \mathbb{F}^{n\times n}: AB_i=B_iA\}=k[B_i]$$
Proof: If $AB_2=B_2A$, then for any basis $\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$, using the fact that $$(B_2)^{i}e_i=e_{1+i} \quad (i=1,2,\dots,n-1)$$
we have:

$Ae_1=f(B_2)e_1$ for some polynomial $f$.
Inductively:
$$ Ae_{i+1}=AB_2e_{i}=B_2Ae_{i}=B_2f(B_2)e_i=f(B_2)e_{i+1}$$
therefore $A=f(B_2)$.

Therefore
$$\{A\in \mathbb{F}^{n\times n}: AB_i=B_iA\quad i=1,2\}= k[B_1]\cap k[B_2]= k[I_n]$$
Hence, any subspace containing $B_1,B_2$ satisfies the above conditions.
But how to find all such subspaces? Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Look at the commutant theorem, the Frobenius decomposition will be very useful here. In any case the result will contain $k [B_1] \cap k[B_2]$ but when you have non-cyclic endomorphisms, it is trickier. Also the center of this algebra is well known

Note that using the kernel lemma on $B_1$ and $B_2$ you can reduce to the case where $\mu (B_1) = P^k$ and $\mu(B_2)=Q^j$ where $P$ and $Q$ are irreducible.

@Zoudelong Since this is a homework assignment, are there any concepts or tools covered in the relevant class that might be applicable here?

Do you work with positive characteristics? If so this becomes really complicated. A perfect field would be cool.

I think your counterexample is already a very nice result showing how difficult this problem is, You have two conjugate matrices that verify the property!

@julio_es_sui_glace Thank you! the characteristic is not specified in the original question. May I ask why a perfect field is good? :-)

Useful information: if you can find the answer when both $u$ and $v$ are nilpotent you have the general answer. for the perfect field it is in fact not useful

I found a necessary and sufficient condition if that interests you

Let $k$ be a field and $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space.
First a small definition

Let $\mathcal E \subset \mathcal L(V)$, its commutant is the subalgebra
$$\mathcal C(\mathcal E) = \{ u \in \mathcal L(V), \, \forall e \in  \mathcal E, \, ue = eu\}$$

Necessary and sufficient condition
Claim: $\mathcal C(u_1,u_2) = k \cdot \operatorname{id}_V$ iff the two following assertions are satisfied:

For all pairs of subspaces $W_1$ and $W_2$ such that $W_1 \oplus W_2 = V$,
$$\left[\forall i,j \in \{1,2\}, \, u_i(W_j) \subset W_j \right] \implies \{W_1,W_2\} = \{0,V\}.$$
Consider the data of $(d_k)_{k=0}^r$ alongside with some basis $(e_{\kappa})_{\kappa \in K}$ of $V$ verifying:


$d_0 = 0$, $d_r = n$.
$d$ is strictly increasing.
$(d_i -d_{i-1})_{1\le i \le r}$ is (weakly) decreasing.
$K = \{(i,j) , \, i \in \{1,\dots , r\}, \, j \in \{1,\dots,d_i-d_{i-1} \}\}$.

Then if we set $d = d_1$ there are no families:

$((\lambda^{l}_{\kappa})_{\kappa \in K})_{1\le l \le d}$ with $\lambda^{l}_{(i,j)} = 0$ if $l > d_i-d_{i-1}$.
$((\mu^{l}_{\kappa})_{\kappa \in K})_{1\le l \le d}$ with $\mu^{l}_{(i,j)} = 0$ if $l > d_i - d_{i-1}$.
Verifying:
$$\forall (i,j) \in K, \, u_1 (e_{i,j}) = \sum_{s=1}^r \sum_{t=1}^{d_s-d_{s-1}} \lambda^j_{s,t}e_{s+r-i,t}\\
\forall (i,j) \in K, \, u_2 (e_{i,j}) = \sum_{s=1}^r \sum_{t=1}^{d_s-d_{s-1}} \mu^j_{s,t}e_{s+r-i,t}$$
with convention $e_{i,j} = 0$ when $i\le 0$.


Remark:

The first condition can be stated as non-co-diagonalisable by (non-trivial) blocks.
The second condition is equivalent to: no non-trivial nilpotent matrix commutes with $u_1$ and $u_2$. There is an alternative version using matrices but I did not find a simple way to put it through.

How did I manage to find this condition? If $n$ is nilpotent, $V$ is the direct sum of cyclic subspaces $V_l = \langle x_l, \dots, n^{k_l-1} x_l \rangle$. We order them by decreasing dimension and in this setting we would define (if I am not mistaken).
$$e_{i,j} = n^{k_j - i} x_j.$$
The condition I imposed on $u_1$ is of the type $ u(n^k x_l) = n^k u(x_l)$ which is necessary and sufficient for commutativity with $n$.
In fact we can observe that any element of the commutant of $n$ is given by the data of the $u(x_l)$ which all need to lie in $\ker n^{k_l}$. If we set $d_k = \dim \ker n^k$ we get
$$ \dim \mathcal C (n)  = \sum_{l=1}^{d_1} d_{k_l} = \sum_{k=1}^r (d_k-d_{k-1} - (d_{k+1}-d_k))d_k =  \sum_{k=1}^r (2d_k-(d_{k-1} + d_{k+1}))d_k.$$
With an Abel's transformation, we get
$$C(n) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (d_{k+1}-d_k)^2$$
which suggests that If we have supplementaries $W_k \oplus \ker n^k = \ker n^{k+1}$, we get an isomorphism between $\mathcal C(n)$ and $\bigoplus_{k=0}^{n-1} \mathcal L(W_k)$


Implication
Let us suppose $\mathcal C(u_1,u_2) = k \cdot \operatorname{id}_V$.
1st condition
Suppose there exists $W_1$ and $W_2$ such that
$$\forall i,j \in \{1,2\}, \, u_i(W_j) \subset W_j .$$
and $W_1 \oplus W_2 = V$
The projector $p$ on $W_1$ parallel to $W_2$ commutes with $u_1$ and $u_2$ thus $p \in \{0,\operatorname{id}\}$, which means either $W_1 = \{0\}$ or $W_1 = V$ which proves the first condition.
2nd condition
The last remark gives the hint: if we had such a basis we could define a nilpotent endomorphism that would both commute with $u_2$ and $u_1$.

Reverse implication
Let $u_1$ and $u_2$ be endomorphisms satisfying the conditions 1. and 2. let us show $\dim \mathcal C (u_1,u_2) = 1$.
A first observation is the following:

Let $\mathcal A$ be a sub-algebra of $\mathcal L(V)$, the dimension of its commutant
$$\mathcal C(\mathcal A) = \{ u \in \mathcal L(V), \, \forall a \in \mathcal A, \, ua = au\}$$
does not depend on the field extension, since $K \otimes_k \mathcal C (\mathcal A)  = \mathcal C(K \otimes_k \mathcal A)$.

This means we can suppose $k$ is algebraically closed (in fact we can use splitting fields so no need of the AoC here but this was too much trouble so I decided to use it).
Take $a$ an endomorphism commuting with both $u_1$ and $u_2$
Let us begin with a small lemma called the kernel lemma:

Let $V$ be a vector space, $u \in \mathcal L (V)$ and $P, \, Q \in k [x]$ such that $P \wedge Q = 1$, then
$$ \ker PQ (a) = \ker P(a) \oplus \ker Q(a).$$
With the canonical projectors $AQ(a)$ and $BP(a)$ where $AP + BQ = 1$.

We set $S = \operatorname{Sp}(a)$, we get (using the kernel lemma)
$$V = \bigoplus_{\lambda \in S} \ker(X-\lambda)^{\alpha_\lambda}(a) .$$
To this we add the following property

If $a$ and $b$ commute, then $b$ stabilises very vector space of the form $\ker p(a)$. This is direct since $p(a)(x) = 0 \implies p(a)b(x) = bp(a)(x) = 0$.

Case 1
Suppose now that $a$ has at least two distinct eigenvalues, then $u_1$ and $u_2$ both stabilise
$$\ker(X-\lambda)^{\alpha_\lambda}(a) \quad \text{and} \quad \bigoplus_{\mu \neq \lambda} \ker(X-\mu)^{\alpha_\mu}(a)$$
which are proper supplementary subspaces, which contradicts the first condition.
Case 2
We now know that $a$ has only one eigenvalue, thus $\Pi_a = (X-\lambda )^\alpha$. This means that $a = \lambda \operatorname{id} + m$ where $m$ is nilpotent of order $\alpha$. But commuting with $a$ is equivalent to commuting with $m$ which is impossible if $\alpha > 1$ given condition $2.$ This means $a = \lambda \operatorname{id}$.

More elegant way of putting condition 2
Let us get back with our condition 2 which is $u$ and $v$ can't commute with the same non-trivial nilpotent endomorphisms. Here it is:

Claim: Condition $2$ is equivalent to the following proposition.
Given the data of:

A direct sum $\bigoplus_{i=1}^r W_i = V$ with $W_r \neq \{0\}$.
For all $k \ge 1$ a pair of an injective linear map $\varphi_k: W_{k+1} \to W_{k}$ alongside with a cokernel, i.e. a supplementary $U_{k} \oplus \varphi_k(W_{k+1}) = W_{k}$.

Then $u$ and $v$ cannot lie in the image by $\psi: \mathcal C \to \mathcal L(V)$ where:
$$\mathcal{C} = \bigoplus_{i=1}^r \mathcal L( U_i,N_i)$$
where $N_i = \bigoplus_{k\le i} W_k$ and for $f \in \mathcal C$,
$$\psi(f)_{|\phi_{k,j} (U_k)} = \sum_{i=1}^r \phi_{i,j} \circ p_i \circ f \circ \phi_{k,j}^{-1}$$
Where:

$\phi_{k,j}$ is bijective map given by $\varphi_{k-j} \circ \dots \circ\varphi_{k-1}: U_k \to W_{k-j}$ on its range and by convention we set $\varphi_1: W_1 \to W_0 = \{0\}$ to make the whole thing consistent (in the case $j\ge k$ $\phi_{k,j} = 0$).
The $p_i$ are the projections given by the decomposition $V = \bigoplus_{i} W_i$.



It is well defined since
$$\begin{align*}
V &= \bigoplus_{k=1}^r W_k = \bigoplus_{k=1}^r \bigoplus_{j\ge k} \varphi_{k} \circ \dots \circ\varphi_{j-1}( U_j)\\
& = \bigoplus_{k=1}^r \bigoplus_{j\ge k} \phi_{j,j-k}  (U_j) \\
&= \bigoplus_{j=1}^r \bigoplus_{k \le j} \phi_{j,k}  (U_j)
\end{align*}$$


Note that $W_i$ is uniquely determined by the $U_k, \, \phi_k, \, k \ge i$ but it is simpler to put it with the $W_i$ in the definition.

Now you ask yourself how the hell did I pull this out of my pants? Think once again about the decomposition given by the Jordan decomposition of $n$ (of order $r$) using cyclic vectors $x_l$ each of "order" $k_l$ and set

$U_i = \langle x_l, \, x_l \,\text{is of order} \, i\}$.
$N_k = \ker n^k$.
$W_k = \bigoplus_{i=k}^r n^{i-k} (U_i)$ is a nice supplementary of $N_{k-1}$ in $N_k$ basically it is one of the maximal subspaces consisting of elements of order $k$ (except for the zero element of course).
$\varphi_k = W_{k+1} \to W_k = n_{|W_{k+1}}$.

If you manage to see the correspondance, everything should make sense since $\psi(\mathcal C)$ is exactly the commutant of such a $n$.
Indeed the data of any commuting endomorphism can be reduced to the data of the image of every cyclic vector. And if $x_l$ is of order $k$ $a(x_l)$ has to be of order $\le k$ (thus in $N_k$).
Now let us observe that
$$\begin{align*} \mathcal{C} 
&=\bigoplus_{i=1}^r \mathcal L( U_i,N_i) \\
&= \bigoplus_{i=1}^r \mathcal L\left( U_i,\bigoplus{k \le i} W_k \right)\\
&= \bigoplus_{i=1}^r \bigoplus_{k=1}^i \mathcal L\left( U_i, W_k \right)\\
&=  \bigoplus_{k=1}^r \mathcal L\left( \bigoplus_{i=k}^r U_i, W_k \right)\\
&= \bigoplus_{k=1}^r \mathcal L( \tilde W_k,W_k)
\end{align*}$$
With $\tilde W_k = \bigoplus_{i=k}^r U_i$ is obviously isomorphic to $W_k$ which in a natural way (using the $\varphi_j$). This leads us to the dimension aspect, let us recover our previous results obtained from an Abel's summation.

We set $d_k = \dim N_k$.
$\dim W_k = \dim N_k - \dim N_{k-1} = d_k - d_{k-1}$.
$\dim U_k = \dim W_k - \dim W_{k+1} = 2d_k - (d_{k+1} + d_{k-1})$.

This means
$$\dim \mathcal C = \sum_{k=1}^r d_k(2d_k-(d_{k+1}-d_{k-1})) = \sum_{k=1}^r (d_k-d_{k-1})^2.$$
In a more "funky" and smooth way, if we had a smooth function $f(x) "=" \dim \ker n^x$ we would have
$$\dim \mathcal C(n) "=" - \int_0^\infty f\cdot f'' = \int_0^\infty {f'}^2 = -\frac{\ln(n)}{2}.$$
Now since this is only sketchy, the only viable interpretation I can give is $\dim \mathcal C (n)$ is the length of the arc given by the dimensions of the iterated kernels: the less it goes into a straight line, the "badder" it is.

Sufficient condition
Here is a simpler to verify statement but it is only sufficient and not necessary.

$u_1$ and $u_2$ don't stabilise any pair of proper supplementary subspaces.
$u_1$ and $u_2$ don't stabilise any non-trivial generalised flag.

The latter are strictly increasing sequences of vector spaces $\{0\} = W_0 \subsetneq W_1 \subsetneq \cdots \subsetneq W_r$ verifying $\dim W_i - \dim W_{i-1}$ is (weakly) decreasing.
But these statements are equivalent to:
The only subspaces that $u_1$ and $u_2$ stabilise are $\{0\}$ and $V$. We could think of this condition as "$u_1$ and $u_2$ are "coprime" since the sub-lattice of stabilised sub-vector spaces with inclusion as order is trivial.
The $B_1$ $B_2$ in your example verify these assumptions, but I can give you a wide range of (more complicated) pairs of nilpotent matrices that verify these assumptions.

Note that we could have used iterated kernels instead of reduction (but both are like the fingers of the hand).


Work in progress
Concrete examples of pairs of nilpotent matrices.
Here is the reminiscence of the idea I originally had (but the motivation was flawed), which is give a sufficient and necessary condition on $n$ and $m$ two nilpotent endomorphisms so that have a trivial commutant. Everything is proven on my paper sheet but it may be vague at some point since this is pretty long.
Minimal and degenerate elements of the sub lattice.
On $\mathbb N^2$ we define the order $(j,k) \preceq (j',k') \iff j \leq j \, \text{and} \, k \le k'$.
We define $D(j,k) = \ker n^j \bigcap \ker m^k$ and $d(j,k) = \dim D(j,k)$. It is not hard to see that $d$ is (weakly) increasing
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
&0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7\\
\hline
0&0 &  0 &0 & 0 &0 &0 & 0 & 0\\
\hline
1&0 &  0 &0 & 0 &0 &0 & 0 & \color{blue}{1}\\ 
\hline
2&0 &  0 &0 & 0 &0 &0 & \color{blue}{1} & 2\\
\hline
3&0 &  0 &0 & 0 &\color{blue}{1} &1 & 2 & 3\\
\hline
4&0 &0 & 0 &\color{blue}{1} &2 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
\hline
5&0 & 0 &\color{blue}{1} &2 & 3 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
\hline
6&0 & 0 &1 &2 & 3 & \color{red}{4} &5 & 6\\
\hline
7&0 &\color{blue}{1} &2 & 3 & {4} &5 & 6 & 7\\
\hline
\end{array}$$
We define a successor an predecessor function $s$ and $p$ by:

For $(j,k) \in \mathfrak M$, $j \neq 1$,
$$s(j,k) = \operatorname{argmax}_1 \left(\mathfrak M \bigsqcup \mathfrak D\right)\bigcap \{0,\dots ,j-1\} \times \mathbb N .$$
For $(j,k) \in \mathfrak M$, $k \neq 1$,
$$p(j,k) = \operatorname{argmax}_2 \left(\mathfrak M \bigsqcup \mathfrak D\right)\bigcap \mathbb N \times \{0,\dots ,k-1\} .$$
For $(j,k) \in \mathfrak D$,
$$s(j,k) = \operatorname{argmax}_1 \left(\mathfrak M \bigsqcup \mathfrak D\right)\bigcap \{0,\dots ,j-1\} \times \{0,\dots,k-1\} \\
p(j,k) = \operatorname{argmax}_2 \left(\mathfrak M \bigsqcup \mathfrak D\right)\bigcap \{0,\dots ,j-1\} \times \{0,\dots,k-1\} .$$

Where $\operatorname{argmax}_i$ takes the index maximising the i-th coordinate.

THANK you very much! Let me take some time to read your post carefully :-)

@Zoudelong I have found a more elegant way to formulate condition $2$ using stability on good subverter spaces
